# How does Brizzly retrieve tweets in spite of a Twitter firewall block?

Tags: twitter, twitter-api

Brizzly is a Twitter client. Though not the best of all the existing clients, what I see as the best in this app is that one can use it at work even if Twitter is blocked. I fail to understand how Brizzly actually does this.

Normal Twitter clients usually talk to the Twitter API, and most of them fail to work at work places at which Twitter is blocked by the firewall. Brizzly too should follow the same procedure to consult Twitter API to display user timeline, but how does it manage to by pass the firewall and retrieve the tweets?

Comment: Well, if it uses the Twitter API server-side and brizzly.com is not blocked by the firewall, it works just as any normal site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not going through your firewall when it talks to the Twitter servers.  Brizzly retrieves content from the Twitter API through its own connection and then stores it on their server and presents it to you while you're logged in.  (It only does this when you're using it, though, otherwise you'd end up using all of your Twitter API limit.)

If your company doesn't allow usage of Twitter during the work day, I wouldn't recommend using Brizzly to get around it.  Also, they may eventually figure it out and block it and similar sites, such as Hootsuite.